# Controlling the choices of when the display sleeps

Tags: 20.04, system-settings

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

In Settings -> Power, there is the Power Saving - Blank Screen option. It has a variety of choices from 1 to 15 minutes plus never.

Is the list of choices configurable? I'd like options between 15 minutes and never.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The answer will be dependant on which version of Ubuntu you’re running. Could you [edit] your question to include this detail? 

Comment: @matigo -- Done. Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @karel Thank you. It doesn't let me configure the available choices, but it gives me what I need.

Comment: @JosephLarson If the above link answered your question please click the "Yes" option to the right of "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.